# parallel subprocesses python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run a list of shell commands as subprocesses in parallel (4 at a time) in Python 2.7. Note **`cmds`** is a valid list of strings generated elsewhere in the code. Here's where I'm at so far...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 
import subprocess

def worker(cmd):
    print cmd 
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=true)

pool = Pool(4)
for cmd in cmds:
    pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd])
```

From this I get no output nor errors. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With all due respect, from remarks below, it comes out, that you require not a **`[PAR]`** -scheduling of the `subprocess`-shelled out commands, but actually just a **`[SEQ]` -schedule, which also blocks, so as to wait, before a next `cmd`-gets shelled "after" the previous was completed.** This is not a parallel-type of schedulling, nor a **[tag:parallel-processing]**

Comment: Sorry I'm still quite green at programming. This is a little over my head. The goal is to run multiple processes simultaneously. Should this then be defined as multiprocessing? I can edit the title and tags if you feel it is appropriate.

Comment: No, Sir. process-scheduling could not get explained as "simultaneously". The principal theory of systems knows **[SERIAL]** ( or [SEQ] a pure serial schedule -- one-after-another ) or **just-[CONCURRENT]** ( or do as you can, if resources permit - some will finish sooner, some later, after shared resources got free to run another task from the list ) or a **true-[PARALLEL]** schedulling -- where all processes are guarranteed to start / execute / finish at the **very same time**. Both CS literature and HPC community members are not purists on using the term just-concurrent and/or true-parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your script ends before the process can run?

I tried your code and I got your same problem.
to solve it  you should close the pool ( *Pool.close()* ) and wait for the processes to end ( *Pool.join()* ).
Check this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

cmds=['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']

def worker(cmd):
    print cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=true)
    p.wait()

pool = Pool(4)
for cmd in cmds:
    pool.apply_async(worker, [cmd])

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Outputs:

```
str1
str2
str3
str4
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the script end when all the processes finish?If I use your strings, I get the same output as you. Strangely, this doesn't work with my list of strings.

Comment: The script ends when it ends, and all the associated processes are deleted. So if the script doesn't wait for the processes to end, it terminates them. 
No idea why it doesn't work for your own code, maybe there are other unrelated problems? Since you said that 'cmds' is a valid list of strings generated elsewhere in the code, I just fabricated one.

Comment: Perhaps. The cmd's will execute just fine individually using subprocess.call. I guess I'm just looking for any clarification on why the script would end with processes still open.

Comment: OK. I see what is going on. Although the script finished, the processes are still running in the background. Is there a way to keep the script open until they all finish? I was under the assumption that with the for loop it would run through the whole list (50+ commands). Instead it just runs as many threads as there there are in the pool (4), then exits.

Comment: I modified the answer, to the proper method suggested by the python's guide (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join)

Comment: Note that the line

    pool = Pool(4)

means that there is a pool of four processes that are run at the same time, as per the guide: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool 

To check it, just increase/decrease the number, and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @oldMammuth. That does the trick.